# Need help in writing query to fethc the results

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization, database-administration

Actually I want query need to pull a unique user count by institution per month.I have written below query but not providing expected output.

```
select s.institutionid, substr(m.timestamp, 1, 7) as d, count(distinct joveuser)
from stats_to_institution as s
join masterstats_innodb as m on s.statid = m.id
where m.timestamp >= '2021-11-15'
group by d, joveuser;
```

The query output looks different than actual output.

**query output**

| institutionid | d | count(distinct joveuser) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2021-11-01 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-11-01 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-11-01 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-11-01 | 1 |
| 3 | 2021-11-01 | 1 |
| 3 | 2021-11-01 | 1 |
| 3 | 2021-11-01 | 1 |
| 3 | 2021-11-01 | 1 |
| 19 | 2021-11-01 | 1 |
| 19 | 2021-11-01 | 1 |
| 19 | 2021-11-01 | 1 |
| 19 | 2021-11-01 | 1 |

**Actual output**

| institutionid | d | count(distinct joveuser) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2021-11-01 | 4 |
| 3 | 2021-11-01 | 4 |
| 19 | 2021-11-01 | 4 |

Please help me on this. What changes should I make in query?

Comment: group by s.institutionid, d ?
I believe you can leave out joveuser because you are already performing a count on it, meaning that you already aggregate (group by is also aggregating).

Comment: @Max I will try and update you

Comment: You are misusing MySQL's [notorious nonstandard extension to GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html). Disable that extension with `SET sql_mode = CONCAT_WS(',',@@sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY')`, then try your query again. You'll need more terms in your GROUP BY clause.